# Directory listing denied on ASP.Net MVC 4 app running in IIS 6 Virtual Directory

Tags: iis-6, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to get ASP.Net MVC 4 working on IIS6 and am running into the always fun Directory Listing Denied error.

Before you start posting about extensionless urls and how I need to read the Haacked blog post.. I have :)  So with that out of the way here is the setup:

I have created a new Web Site and configured it to use ASP.Net 4.0.  I had to do this because the existing Default Web Site is configured for ASP.Net 2.0 and this breaks extensionless urls.  Under the new web site I created a Virtual Directory with Read/Write/Log Vists/Index this resource options selected and  execute permissions set to Scripts.

I have verified that ASP.Net v4.0.30319 is in the Web Service Extensions list and is allowed.  I have also verified that the .axd mapping is setup correctly in my virtual directories mapping configuration.

I am completely and totally stumped..

As a side bit of trivia I had this working with the web site pointing directly at my ASP.Net 4 web app but we need this to be done via a virtual directory instead.  The fact I had this working should mean that the EnableExtensionlessUrl registry setting is not a problem.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had faced the same problem and it got cleared when I added "Wildcard application mapping" (`.*`) to `aspnet_isapi.dll` with unchecked option "Verify that file exists"

> Application -> Properties -> Directory -> Configuration -> Mappings ->
>   Insert -> Browse to
>   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll ->
>   Uncheck "Verify that file exists" -> Ok

Now the site is opening fine without any issues.

Comment: probably a stupid question, but I keep getting `Invalid extension markup` when I leave the field blank. Also tried the asterisk * wild card, but didn't accepted it.

Comment: I added the .mvc extension and then on that extension added the wildcard application map. Even though my routes don't use .mvc,  this it was needed to enter a valid entry in the Extension box in the "Add/Edit Application Extension Mapping" dialog.

Comment: This worked for me too, with an MVC 3 application.  But why does it work?  And what other problems have I introduced by adding this mapping?

Comment: @JPHellemons I guess what you need to put in the extension field is `.*`, I just edited the answer to make this more clear

Answer (score 2):

Similar issue: We installed MVC4 on an IIS6 box, set up everything as described, and got same error:

```
Directory Listing Denied
This Virtual Directory does not allow contents to be listed.
```

For us, the final fix was to add the UrlRoutingModule to the web.config:

```
  <add name="UrlRoutingModule"
       type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

Which makes sense, but I don't know why we needed to explicitly add it and others didn't.  (We are running in a directory under Sharepoint, maybe related...)

Comment: Under what node does `<add name="UrlRoutingModule" ...>` go?