# VB.NET web api returns "404 Not Found"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Good afternoon everyone. This is my first post here. I am also somewhat new to developing web services in .NET, although I have been developing websites and applications for a long time. I just started a new job and this is my first project.

I am trying to create a web service that is called from an iPad application. The service should accept a JSON object, query a database using parameters from the JSON, then return a JSON string based on the results. I followed this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api. Here are the pertinents and such:

- I'm using Visual Studio 2010 SP1
- We use VB.NET here (I asked about C# and was rebuffed harshly)
- I installed and am using MVC 4
- The server is remote, and runs IIS 6
- It is running the .NET 4.0 framework
- My project is in the right pool and is configured to .NET 4.0
- My project has the Wildcard Script Map
- In my app, the Application_Start methods are in the correct order
- I even added the MVC "Deployable Dependencies" for good measure, but I probably didn't need them

Here is my AJAX call to the service:

```
    var uri = 'api/status';

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: uri,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {},
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function (req, status, error) {
                console.log("req = " + req + ", status = " + status + ", error = " + error);
            }
        });         


    });
```

Here is my controller, named StatusController:

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Web.Http

Namespace FadecStatus.Controllers
    Public Class StatusController
        Inherits ApiController
        Private engines As FadecStatus.Models.Engine() = New FadecStatus.Models.Engine() {New FadecStatus.Models.Engine() With { _
            .name = "PC-24-0001_2014-04-30_05-55.file", _
            .size = "120KB", _
            .uploadDate = "04/30/2014", _
            .status = "Sent" _
        }}

        Public Function GetAllEngines() As IEnumerable(Of FadecStatus.Models.Engine)
            Return engines
        End Function

    End Class
End Namespace
```

After all of this, I still get a "404 Not Found" error when trying to access the service. I've been researching this and experimenting for the better part of a week, including exploring some legacy formats. I think this is the newest and best option for what I want to do. Any suggestions would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does the service work on your own machine?

Comment: I haven't tried to run it locally until now. When I select View in Browser, I get the following error message: "Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified." I found some info about this, talking about references and assemblies, but I don't know enough about .NET and VS to make the appropriate corrections. My project currently consists of an HTML page making an AJAX call (on load) to my service, which has one method - that's it.

Comment: I did a little more digging, and I decided to remove the Deployable Dependencies. They seem to be the source of the above error, and I'm almost certain I don't need them. As a result, when I try to run the app locally now, I get a 'Server Too Busy' error displayed in my browser.

Comment: I spent a significant amount of time trying to get my application to display locally, until I finally realized the problem is either my version of IE (8), or the 'View in Browser' functionality is messed up. I viewed the site locally in Firefox and I can finally see my HTML, but the console has a 500 Internal Server Error. I added my custom elements to the reference table in my Application Configuration Panel, but this did not change anything. If anyone has any ideas, **please** help. I'm starting to lose hope.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. There were two steps involved:

First, I couldn't run my application in debug mode. The browser would open then almost immediately close with an "Access Denied" error. I discovered that the MVC Project creates a second web.config file in the Views folder. The root web.config file has the following section to allow anonymous access that I copied to the web.config file in the Views folder:

```
<security>
  <authentication>
    <anonymousAuthentication userName="" />
  </authentication>
</security>
```

I received the "Server Too Busy" error after this, but inserting a breakpoint in my code allowed local debugging to work semi-consistently.

Now that local debugging was fixed, my second step was was to fix the dev site. At this point, I was able to determine the problem was specifically with the configuration of .NET on the remote server. I checked this initially, but apparently I didn't do it right. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622102/directory-listing-denied-on-asp-net-mvc-4-app-running-in-iis-6-virtual-directory) fixed my problem. Thanks Indomitable!